# Missing default value in nested field of kubernetes custom resource

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-custom-resources

I have a Custom Resource Definition which has nested fields with default values (some boilerplate omitted for brevity):

```yaml
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
spec:
  scope: Namespaced
  group: thismatters.stackoverflow
  names:
    kind: BadDefault
  versions:
  - name: v1alpha
    schema:
      openAPIV3Schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          spec:
            type: object
            properties:
              regularThing:
                type: integer
                default: 6
              shouldDefault:
                type: object
                properties:
                  nestedThing:
                    type: integer
                    default: 12
```

Whenever I create a resource of this kind without specifying the `shouldDefault` object:

```yaml
apiVersion: thismatters.stackoverflow/v1alpha
kind: BadDefault
metadata:
  name: blank-demo
spec: 
  regularThing: 7
```

The default value for `.shouldDefault.nestedThing` doesn't appear when the resource is `describe`d:

```yaml
apiVersion: thismatters.stackoverflow/v1alpha
kind: BadDefault
metadata:
  name: blank-demo
spec: 
  regularThing: 7
```

If I update the resource with this manifest:

```yaml
apiVersion: thismatters.stackoverflow/v1alpha
kind: BadDefault
metadata:
  name: blank-demo
spec: 
  regularThing: 7
  shouldDefault: {}
```

Then the nested field default value is populated when `describe`d:

```yaml
apiVersion: thismatters.stackoverflow/v1alpha
kind: BadDefault
metadata:
  name: blank-demo
spec: 
  regularThing: 7
  shouldDefault:
    nestedThing: 12
```

Is there anything I can do in the CRD to remove the need for the `shouldDefault: {}` line in the resource manifest and have the default values populate in the nested fields?

My cluster is on Kubernetes version 1.19.

Comment: You are using deprecated version of Kubernetes. Could you update it to [supported one](https://endoflife.date/kubernetes)?

Comment: 1.19 is still supported in EKS (even 1.18 is still supported). Is there a known issue in 1.19 that prevents default values of nested fields from being autopopulated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `default` property to the `shouldDefault` object fixes this:

```yaml
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
spec:
  scope: Namespaced
  group: thismatters.stackoverflow
  names:
    kind: BadDefault
  versions:
  - name: v1alpha
    schema:
      openAPIV3Schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          spec:
            type: object
            properties:
              regularThing:
                type: integer
                default: 6
              shouldDefault:
                type: object
                default: {}   #  <-- this was added
                properties:
                  nestedThing:
                    type: integer
                    default: 12
```